# How to Upgrade/Downgrade subscription in Flutter using in_app_purchase package

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

For purchases, I am using the [in](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#upgrading-or-downgrading-an-existing-in-app-subscription)[apppurchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#upgrading-or-downgrading-an-existing-in-app-subscription) package. The package provides features for upgrading and downgrading packages. But I am unable to upgrade or downgrade the package. I am sharing [details](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#upgrading-or-downgrading-an-existing-in-app-subscription) found on their package page.

[image]*
Currently, I am stuck fetching the PurchaseDetails object (oldPurchaseDetails). Has anyone used this feature of the in_app_purchase package?

I reviewed that package code and followed their shared code. But I didn't find a way to get the old purchase details.

Answer (score 1):

the sample doesn't work if you're not testing it with recent stuff. If you stored the transaction token on the server, here you go:

```
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/in_app_purchase_android.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/billing_client_wrappers.dart';



final verificationData = PurchaseVerificationData(localVerificationData: token!, serverVerificationData: token!, source: token!);

// the only thing here that matters for this object is token!
final wrapper = PurchaseWrapper.fromJson({
    "orderId": "",
    "packageName": "",
    "purchaseTime": 0,
    "purchaseToken": token!,
    "signature": "",
    "products": [],
    "isAutoRenewing": false,
    "originalJson": "",
    "isAcknowledged": false,
    "purchaseState": 0
  });

final oldPurchaseDetails = GooglePlayPurchaseDetails(
  productID: currentPlan!, // <-- plan id for the old one
  verificationData: verificationData,
  transactionDate: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
  billingClientPurchase: wrapper,
  status: PurchaseStatus.purchased,
);
```

Had to go dink with the source, but here it is so u can see if it changes in the future or something. Hope this helps!

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/557d3284ac9dda32a1106bb75be8a23bdccd2f96/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_android/lib/src/in_app_purchase_android_platform.dart#L134

Answer (score 0):

For getting the old purchase you need to send the previous purchased plan id only then you can get old purchase details here is code that may be help you

```
 GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? _getOldSubscription(
      ProductDetails productDetails, Map<String, PurchaseDetails> purchases) {
    // This is just to demonstrate a subscription upgrade or downgrade.
    // Please remember to replace the logic of finding the old subscription Id as per your app.
    // The old subscription is only required on Android since Apple handles this internally
    // by using the subscription group feature in iTunesConnect.

     var _kSubscriptionId =
        "<Product ID which you want to purchase>";

    var _kPastSubscriptionId = "<Old Product ID which you already purchased>";

    GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? oldSubscription;
    if (productDetails.id == _kSubscriptionId &&
        purchases[_kPastSubscriptionId] != null) {
      oldSubscription =
          purchases[_kPastSubscriptionId]! as GooglePlayPurchaseDetails;
    }
    return oldSubscription;
  }
```

This will return you the old plan detail.